# кредит в пять миллиардов

Tags: управление

Китай выделяет кредит в пять миллиардов долларов.

или:

Китай выделяет кредит пять миллиардов долларов.

Китай выделяет кредит размером в пять миллиардов долларов.

Китай выделяет кредит в размере пяти миллиардов долларов.

Китай выделяет кредит на сумму пять миллиардов долларов.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант более употребителен, но и остальные вполне возможны. Кому как нравится, любой не ошибка.